# Postgresql too many clients error on linux server

Tags: database, postgresql

when i try connect postgresql 9.0 server on linux i get too many clients connected already. I tried increasing `max_connections` from 100 to 200 and start the server it doest take the max connections. What should i change on the linux server

**Eclipse LogCat**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a FAQ and is discussed in [Number of Database Connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) on the PostgreSQL wiki.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase **max_connections** and persist this value is modifying the **postgresql.conf** file, so first of all, check if the value has changed (after restarting the server):

```
show max_connections
```

If the value DID NOT change, there's something wrong with your procedure (file permissions maybe?).  If the value DID change, you might try with a higher value (weird, but might depend on your application connection requirements, OR a connection leak).